# Linux Powershell inserting into PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, powershell

I'm not used to Powershell, so I'm sorry if this is a noob question.

I would like to extract data from WSUS Windows Internal Database and insert it into a PostgreSQL running on Linux.

I currently have the Powershell code that connects to the remote WSUS DDBB from Windows and gets the data I want.

I searched in this forum and Google. I have installed the Postgre x64 ODBC driver, created the database connection and found the following code that is supposed to insert properly into de DDBB.

```
function Set-ODBC-Data{
    param([string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'))
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString= "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=SOMENAME;Port=5432;Database=DBNAME;Uid=SOMEUSER;Pwd=SOMEPASS;"
    $cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
    $conn.open()
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $conn.close()
}
$query = "query statement"
set-odbc-data -query $query
```

I've also seen that Powershell can be run on Linux in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-macos-and-linux?view=powershell-6#centos-7). 
 Could someone tell me if it would be possible to run the Powershell from CentOS, for example, and make the insertions in the remote Postgre BBDD and guide me?

The first option would be to run the Powershell from Linux to obtain the information from the WSUS database and, in the same or different script on Linux, make the insertions in the Postgre database. Is it possbile to run this Powershell from Linux or do you see any impediment?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: PowerShell 6 is built on .Net Core, and that [doesn't have `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/) so your code won't work directly on Linux.

Comment: Your Windows script could output the data in a format that PostreSQL could read and import.  Or use your windows script to create a bunch of SQL insert queries and execute on PostgeSQL directly.

Comment: The first option would be to run the Powershell from Linux to obtain the information from the WSUS database and, in the same or different script, make the insertions in the Postgre database. Is it possbile to run this Powershell from Linux or, on the contrary, do you see any impediment?

Comment: Powershell 7+ now allows for ODBC connections on linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685081/7411885